# android resource not found

Tags: android, xml

I put this in my LinearLayout

```
style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"
```

but i got an error like this

> No resource found that matches the
>   given name (at 'style' with value
>   '?android:attr/buttonBarStyle').

How to solve this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which version you are using? as style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle" is available in Android v3.0

check this for reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using `style="@android:style/ButtonBar"`. This style is available in older version of Android, but `android:attr/buttonBarStyle` is available only in Android 3.0, like Zoombie has already said.